# How to center text in my div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to center the text in the div, but I have no idea how to. If someone could please help me, that would be absolutely wonderful.

CSS

```
#nav    {
width: 425px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Mager;
}

#nav li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
}

#nav li:hover   {
opacity: .6;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav">

<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Soundcloud</li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Facebook</li>
    <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need every li to be on a line or what ?

Comment: for aligning texts..you can use text-align:center, text-align:left, text-align:right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `text-align` property:

```
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But note that you are using `float:left`, so unless you set a width, you won't actually *see* any centering.

[Here's a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/d92n6mes/)

Comment: It's still not working, here is a screenshot of the image along with the code.                                                                  [imgur](http://imgur.com/y71ZfUq)

Comment: An alternative to setting a width is just to get rid of the float:left.

Comment: @Sagelane What's not working? Are you trying to center the *entire menu*?

Comment: @MichaelHays It seems like OP wants to display the `li`s on a single line, in which case the float is necessary.

Comment: `float: left` is bad news -- a better approach is to use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.  But I think regardless, you got the OP what he needed.  :-)

Comment: Even with the float, it's still not showing them side by side. Could you give me an example of code that would make the words side by side?

Comment: @Sagelane Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/d92n6mes/1/). It uses `display: inline` instead of `float: left`. As Michael Hays pointed out, that's better anyway. :) Note: the text wraps to a second line because of the hard-coded width on `#nav`. You don't really need that if you're trying to center it anyway, so I would remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have make a little fiddle you can see...
http://jsfiddle.net/Azzamean/fjnuw/67/

HTML:

```
  <div id="menu">
     <header>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sound Cloud</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
 a:link, a:visited {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#E80000;
  }
  li {
    display:inline-block;
   }
  #menu {
  background-color:#E80000;
  text-align:center;
  }
```